# How to reset vuetify's v-input-file

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js

How can we reset vuetify's v-input-file? To clear the form input file after each upload?

```
        <v-file-input
          label="Upload"
          accept="image/*"
          @change="selectFile"
        >
        </v-file-input>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's rather simple to do. First there is a prop `clearable` which allows the user to clear the input. Second if you set your data model to `null` then the input field is cleared as well.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-file-input
      v-model="filename"
      clearable="true" 
      label="File input"
      ></v-file-input>
    <v-row justify="center">    
     <v-btn dark
       color="secondary"
       @click="filename = null"
     >Clear</v-btn>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>       
</div>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      filename: null,
    }
  },
})
```

Comment: unfortunately validation through :rules still still throws an error after clearing...

Answer (score 4):

I had to go into the input component and clear the value

```js
this.$refs.fileupload.$refs.input.value = null
```

Answer (score 3):

Add an attribute `:key="componentKey"` and increment it in your code.

```
   <v-file-input
      label="Upload"
      accept="image/*"
      @change="selectFile"
      :key="componentKey"
    >
    </v-file-input>
```

In your javascript

```js
   data() {
      return {
        componentKey: 0
      }
    },
    
    methods: {
      selectFile(event) {
        // your code to deal with event/file
        this.componentKey++;
      }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, after incrementing the file-input doesn't re-render and vanishes from the page.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's too late but here is an answer without getting any errors in the console: `this.$refs.fileupload.reset()`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use ref for reset file after upload.

```js
this.$refs.fileupload.value=null
```

```html
<v-file-input
    ref="fileupload"
          label="Upload"
          accept="image/*"
          @change="selectFile"
        >
        </v-file-input>
```

Comment: I received this warning using $refs [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "value"

Answer (score 0):

`reset()` or `.value = null` did not work for me, but the following seems to call the same code that gets called when hitting the X clear button in the input:

```
  const fileUploader = (this.$refs.fileUpload as any)
  upload.clearableCallback()
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this worked out like a charm:

```js
if (this.$refs.fileInput) {
   this.$refs.fileInput.reset() //console.log(this.$refs.fileInput)
}
```

And here I just have added the `ref` for the `v-file-input`:

```html
<v-file-input
   ref="fileInput"
   small-chips
   label="File input w/ small chips"
   accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
   @change="handleChangeFileInput"
></v-file-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<v-file-input>` expects an array so you can use the `data` component option to set the value for `<v-file-input>` to an empty array (or `null`) to reset it:

```
<template>
    <v-file-input
        label="File input"
        v-model="file">
    </v-file-input>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      file: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    resetFileInput() {
      this.file = []
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

You would still need a button and bind `resetFileInput` to the button using `@click="resetFileInput"` to trigger the reset, or you can just reset `this.file` in some other method so that a button is not necessary.